# Trouble writing log data with Node.JS I/O

Tags: node.js

I am interfacing Node.JS with a library that provides an iterator-style access to data:

```
next = log.get_next()
```

I effectively want to write the following:

```
while (next = log.get_next()) {
    console.log(next);
}
```

and redirect `stdout` to a file (e.g. `node log.js > log.txt`). This works well for small logs, but for large lots the output file is empty and my memory usage goes through the roof.

It appears I don't fully understand I/O in node, as a simple infinite loop that writes a string to the console also exhibits the same behavior.

Some advice on how to accomplish this task would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WriteStream class buffers i/o and if you're never yielding the thread, the queued writes never get serviced. The best approach is to write a reasonable chunk of data, then wait for the buffer to clear before writing again. The WriteStream class emits a 'drain' event that tells you when the buffer has been fully flushed. Here's an example:

```
var os = require('os');

process.stdout.on('drain', function(){
  dump();
});

function dump(){
  for (var i=0; i<10000; i++)
    console.log('xxxx');
  console.error(os.freemem());
}

dump();
```

If you run like:

```
node testbuffer > output
```

you'll see that the file grows periodically and the memory reaches a steady state.

Answer (score 0):

The library you're interfacing with ought to accept a callback. Node.js is designed to be non-blocking. I think that perhaps `console.log` keeps returning control to the loop (and `log.get_next()`) before it sends the output.

If the module was rewritten to make get_next support a callback, improved code might be like this:

```
var log_next = function() {
  console.log(next);
  log.get_next(log_next);
};
log.get_next(log_next);
```

(There are libraries and patterns that could make this code prettier.)

If the code is only synchronous and has to stay as it is, calling setTimeout with 0 or another small number could keep it from blocking the entire process.

```
var log_next = function() {
  console.log(log.get_next());
  setTimeout(log_next, 0);
};
log_next();
```